# Why is my PHP 7.1 script saying that login credentials are incorrect even if they are correct?

Tags: php, authentication, credentials

I am making a login script in PHP and almost everything seems to work fine, if I make an account, it works, but if I try to sign in with the credentials of that account.
I get the alert that the credentials are wrong.
I saved also the password here in a text file and I agree with you that it's stupid, but it is for a school assignment so it won't matter.

Personally I think that there's something wrong with my login script, but I'm not sure. (And because it's for school I need to stick as close as possible to the code layout.)

Here's the code:

signup.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST["usrname"]);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["mail"]);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["pass"]);
    $passwordConfirm = htmlspecialchars($_POST["passconfirm"]);

    trim($username);
    trim($email);

    function checkUserData() {
        // things to do .A
        // things to do .B
        // things to do .C 

        // check if passwords are the same #### this doesn't seem to work correct. Why not?
        if ($password != $passwordConfirm) {
            echo "<script>alert('passwords are not matching');
            location.href='signup.html';
            </script>";
            return false;
        } 

        elseif ($password == $passwordConfirm) {
             return true;
        }

    }

    if (checkUserData()) {
        // saving user
        $file = fopen("users.txt", "ab");
        if (!$file) {
            echo "Couldn't open file!";
        }

        $profile = $username . "*" . $password . "*" . $email . "\n";

        fwrite($file, $profile, strlen($profile));

        if (fclose($file)) {
            echo "<script>alert('Account is created');
            location.href='login.html';
            </script>";
        }

        elseif (!fclose($file)) {
            echo "Couldn't close file!";
        } else {
            echo "An error ocurred while creating an account, try again later.";
        }
    }

}
?>
```

login.php

```
<?php
$username = htmlspecialchars($_POST["usrname"]);
$password = htmlspecialchars($_POST["pass"]);

$file = fopen("users.txt", "r");
if (!$file) {
    echo "Couldn't open file!";
}

while (!feof($file)) {
    $account = fgets($file);
    $account = explode("*", $account);
    if ($account[1] == $username && $account[2] == $password) {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["USER"] = $username;
        $_SESSION["STATUS"] = 1;
        $_SESSION["ID"] = $_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"];
        echo "<script>
        alert('You are now logged in as ".$_SESSION['USER'].".');
        location.href='welcome.php'
        </script>";
    } 
}

echo "<script>
alert('Username or password incorrect');
location.href='login.html'
</script>";
?>
```

Comment: the way you are using trim() has no effect.

Comment: But the way you are using `htmlspecialchars()` may well be having an effect. Dont mess with userid and password, and use bound and parameterised queries for this AND `password_hash()`

Comment: [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).... `$password` and `$passwordConfirm` variables don't exist in the `checkUserData()` function

Comment: You don't pass your password to the function. It will compare null with null.

Comment: Try outputing what `$account` and `$username`, `$password` have values for. Also try outputting `var_dump($account[1] == $username)` and also the one with the password.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is for text to be displayed in HTML. To sanitize text going to the database use prepared statements and add some validation on allowed characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems the $account array's index starts from 0.
change your code in login file at line 13 to

```
if ($account[0] == $username && $account[1] == $password)
```

should solve it.

[PHP manual for explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)